# vusjs dropzone image upload with firebase (storage is not a function)

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, firebase-storage, dropzone.js

Been following [this guide](https://medium.com/javascript-in-plain-english/drag-and-drop-image-upload-with-vue-js-dropzone-and-firebase-dd6fb7e2e54b) to help me get image uploads within a small VueJS appp, with not much success. I keep getting the error:

> TypeError: _config_firebaseInit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.default.storage is not a function

Here is my firebase init file:

```
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/storage";
import firebaseConfig from "./firebaseConfig";

const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var storage = firebase.storage();

export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

I have a normal form with a vue-dropzone element in place and using the following code:

```
import firebase from "../../../config/firebaseInit";
import { uuid } from "vue-uuid";
import vue2Dropzone from "vue2-dropzone";
import "vue2-dropzone/dist/vue2Dropzone.min.css";

export default {
  name: "new-listing",
  components: {
    vueDropzone: vue2Dropzone
  },
  data() {
    return {
      dropzoneOptions: {
        url: "https://httpbin.org/post",
        thumbnailWidth: 150,
        thumbnailHeight: 150,
        addRemoveLinks: false,
        acceptedFiles: ".jpg, .jpeg, .png",
        dictDefaultMessage: `<p class='text-default'><i class='fa fa-cloud-upload mr-2'></i> Drag Images or Click Here</p>
          <p class="form-text">Allowed Files: .jpg, .jpeg, .png</p>
          `
      },
      images: [],
      id: null,
      title: null,
      subTitle: null,
      endDate: null,
      maxTickets: null,
      question: null,
      answer1: null,
      answer2: null,
      answer3: null
    };
  },

  methods: {
    saveListing() {
      firebase.collection("listings")
        .add({
          title: this.title,
          subTitle: this.subTitle,
          endDate: this.endDate,
          maxTickets: this.maxTickets,
          question: this.question,
          answer1: this.answer1,
          answer2: this.answer2,
          answer3: this.answer3
        })
        .then(docRef => {
          console.log("Client added: ", docRef.id);
          this.$router.push("/");
        })
        .catch(error => {
          console.error("Error adding listing: ", error);
        });
    },
    async afterComplete(upload) {
      var imageName = uuid.v1();
      this.isLoading = true;
      try {
        //save image
        let file = upload;
        var metadata = {
          contentType: "image/png"
        };

        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var imageRef = storageRef.child(`images/${imageName}.png`);

        await imageRef.put(file, metadata);
        var downloadURL = await imageRef.getDownloadURL();
        this.images.push({ src: downloadURL });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
      this.$refs.imgDropZone.removeFile(upload);
    }
  }
};
```

I also checked the firebase docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/start) and I think I am right but its not working.

Answer (score 1):

Your init file (`FirebaseInit`) only exports Firestore:

```
export default firebaseApp.firestore();
```

But then in your other file you import this, and try to call `storage()` on it. Since you only exported Firestore, this is equivalent to `firebase.firestore().storage()`, which doesn't exist.

You should probably export your entire `firebaseApp` or the entire `firebase` namespace:

```
export default firebase // export default firebaseApp
```

In the other page you'll then have to use `firebase.firestore()` and `firebase.storage()` to access those services, so for example:

```
firebase.firestore().collection("listings")`
```

Comment: Hi Frank, tried both options but they just produce an error:

Error in created hook: "TypeError: _config_firebaseInit__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.default.collection is not a function"

Comment: You'll have to expand `firebase.collection("listings")` to become `firebase.firestore().collection("listings")`.